# How to properly prepare Apache Ignite for large cache values?

Tags: java, ignite

I have an `IgniteCache<String, byte[]>`

The values in this cache can be small all the way to several hundred megabytes.

From the documentation I've read, there is no hard limit on the value of a cache entry. Which is reassuring.

But are there any gotchas for my use-case that I need to worry about?

For example, any configuration settings I need to set specifically for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, Ignite uses byte buffers to serialize data, and those buffers are limited by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so 2GiB is the maximum cache entry size.

Some Ignite APIs process data in batches, it is a good idea to reduce batch/page sizes when dealing with large entries:

- `Query.pageSize` (applies to Scan, SQL, Continuous queries) - default is 1024
- `IgniteDataStreamer.perNodeBufferSize`, `perThreadBufferSize` - defaults are 512 and 4096

Comment: question - so the only thing i am doing is get and put. very simple cache here - just preventing repeated expensive database lookups from pummeling my backend. given that i am only doing get and putAsync, what is the recommended setting?

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend having entries larger than a few MB. It may cause all sorts of network or memory issues.

If you have to, you need to try with largest possible values and then adjust settings until you are good. One thing I can think off, setting `TcpCommunicationSpi.ackSendThreshold` to some small value such as 4 (default 32) to avoid these large messages sitting in queues. But there's probably a lot of things to tune.